# Iterating over more than three arrays in Scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

I have to turn a bunch of silly comma separated Strings into, finally, Objects. I first split the strings to Arrays. Then I need to iterate over all of them simultaneously and build an Object out of the four values.

```
val s1 = Array(1,2,3)
val s2 = Array("a","b","c")
val s3 = Array(10,20,30)
val s4 = Array("u","v","w")
```

The target Object looks like this:

```
case class Data(a: Int, b: String, c: Int, d: String)
```

The first Data object has to print

```
Data(1,a,10,u)
```

And so on. I found a solution for three items:

```
(s1, s2, s3).zipped foreach { (v1, v2, v3) =>
  println(v1, v2, v3)
}
```

Which prints:

```
(1,a,10)
(2,b,20)
(3,c,30)
```

With four arrays or more, this won't do it. Zipped is not defined for a 4-tuple:

```
error: value zipped is not a member of (Array[Int], Array[String], Array[Int], Array[String])
```

My Scala is a bit rusty so maybe I am missing the obvious (like an iteration with index or something).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not pretty, but should work (with arbitrary amount of row-lenghts)

```
val items: Array[Array[Any]] = Array (
  Array(1,2,3),
  Array("a","b","c"),
  Array(10,20,30),
  Array("u","v","w")
)

items.transpose.map {
  case Array(a: Int, b: String, c: Int, d: String) => Data(a,b,c,d)
}
// Array(Data(1,a,10,u), Data(2,b,20,v), Data(3,c,30,w))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use indices?

```
for (i <- 0 until Seq(s1,s2,s3,s4).map(_.length).min)
yield Data(s1(i), s2(i), s3(i), s4(i))
```

This scales arbitrarily far, and handles length mismatches in the same way as zip/zipped (by truncation).

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
((s1, s2, s3).zipped, s4).zipped foreach { case ((v1, v2, v3), v4) =>
  println(v1, v2, v3, v4)
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Marius Danila answer

```
val zipped = (s1 zip s2 zip s3 zip s4) map {
  case (((a, b), c), d) => Data(a, b, c, d)
}
```